# Linux/Python: Monitor /proc/acpi files without polling?

Tags: python, linux, pygtk, inotify, pygobject

Is there any way to monitor `/proc` files, such as

```
/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state
/proc/acpi/ac_adapter/ADP0/state
```

in a non-polling fashion, similar to inotify on a normal filesystem?

I want to do this in a PyGTK app, so I tried using PyGObject's gio.FileMonitor, but no dice. A Python solution that plays well with `gtk.main()` would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can get the information you want by listening to the ACPI events. Preferably not directly (/proc/acpi/event), but via acpid or other high-level interface.

Update: the other, higher level interface is the DBus interface provided by DeviceKit-power / UPower.

Files in /proc are not regular files, rather a simple interface to kernel state, so many facilities for regular files won't work there.

Comment: It does look as though DeviceKit-power is the current best way to do this.